# Returning an Object "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to return my RecipeModel object but get an error of 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'. I did use all the properties I have created in my struct. I already tried removing ",json:[String: Any]" and checked if I missed a bracket. What am I missing?
Thank you for help.

```
func parseRecipes(forJSON json: [String: Any]) -> [RecipeModel] {
    guard let recipesData = json["recipeTiles"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return [] }

    let recipes = recipesData.compactMap({ (recipesDictionary) -> RecipeModel? in
    let recipeTypeString = recipesDictionary["type"] as? String
    let imageString = recipesDictionary["image"] as? String
    let bgTypeString = recipesDictionary["backgroundType"] as? String
    let bgType = BackgroundType(rawValue: bgTypeString ?? "")
    let title = recipesDictionary["title"] as? String
    let ingredients = recipesDictionary["ingredients"] as? [[String: String]]
    let directions = recipesDictionary["directions"] as? [[String: String]]

        
        return RecipeModel(type: recipeTypeString, image: imageString, title: title, ingredients: ingredients, directions: directions, bgType: bgType) // Error pops up here

        })
      
      return recipes
      
  }
```

This is my RecipeModel struct where all the let properties are listed

```
struct RecipeModel {
var viewMode: CardViewMode = .card
var type: String
var title: String
var ingredients: [IngredientModel]
var directions: [DirectionModel]
var image: String
var backgroundType: BackgroundType = .light


init(type: String, title: String, ingredients: [String: Any], directions: [String: Any], image: String, bgType: BackgroundType, json: [String: Any]) {
    self.type = type
    self.title = title
    self.image = image
    self.backgroundType = bgType
    self.ingredients = []
    if let jsonIngredients = json["ingredients"] as? [String: Any] {
        for jsonIngredient in jsonIngredients {
            self.ingredients.append(IngredientModel(json: jsonIngredient as? [String: Any] ?? [:]))

            }
        }

    self.directions = []
    if let jsonDirections = json["directions"] as? [String: Any] {
        for jsonDirections in jsonDirections {
            self.directions.append(DirectionModel(json: jsonDirections as? [String: Any] ?? [:]))
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initializer is a function. A function declaration is a contract. When you call the function you must keep that contract. I appreciate that it is not a very helpful error message, and it might be worth filing a bug report about that, but the nature of the actual error is quite simple.

So, the error is on the line where you call a RecipeModel initializer like this:

```
RecipeModel(type: recipeTypeString, image: imageString, title: title, ingredients: ingredients, directions: directions, bgType: bgType)
```

Well, there is no such initializer. The initializer is this:

```
init(type: String, title: String, ingredients: [String: Any], directions: [String: Any], image: String, bgType: BackgroundType, json: [String: Any]) {
```

Your call must include all of those parameters. They must be in that order (`type:`, then `title:` — you've put `image:` instead — and so on) and it must not omit any of them (you have omitted `json:` entirely). (**EDIT** And of course the types of the passed arguments must match the declared types of the corresponding parameters.)

Comment: hi matt, thanks for your reply. now even though I followed you suggested code line, the error does not get fixed. I wrote "return RecipeModel(type: recipeTypeString, title: title, ingredients: ingredients, directions: directions, image: imageString, bgType: bgType, json: [String : Any])" The order is correct, right?

Comment: Yes but the types are not the same. For example `recipeTypeString` is an Optional String, but the initializer expects a String. And so on for all the rest. Not only the parameter names but the types of the values you supply must exactly match what the initializer declaration requires. Just look at the `init` that _you yourself wrote_ and call it in a way that obeys _your own rules_ for what the caller must say. (Added that to my answer.)

Comment: I didn't actually write all of code myself. It was part of a tutorial and now I'm making some bigger changes. Just to clarify, since I don't want to change the let = recipeTypeString as? String, I have to tell the initializer to expect a Optional String.

Comment: Wherever the code comes from, it’s you talking now! So I’m just saying you have to speak consistently with yourself one way or the other.

Comment: Ok, but even when I change the types to match my initializer `return RecipeModel(type: String, title: String, ingredients: [String : Any], directions: [String : Any], image: String, bgType: BackgroundType, json: [String : Any])` the object still complains.